# Running power shell on a remote VM

Tags: powershell, remote-server

Say I have a got a virtual machine VM1 with windows server 2008 installed on it. So it probably has PowerShell 2.0 installed on it but I can install PowerShell version 3.0 if needed to solve this problem. Now say my machine is Windows 7 64 bit with SP 1, I want to execute a PowerShell script on my machine that opens the PowerShell (not literally opening the window) on VM1 and executes some commands on the PowerShell of that VM1. And I do have administrative login credentials for that VM1 and my machine (both).

How can something like this be achieved ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you affraid of googling powershell execute remote command?

Comment: @ I am reading now :-) but just asked the question so that I can look in the right direction (which I got from alroc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work the same on version 2 & version 3, but you must have [PSRemoting enabled](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849694.aspx). Once that's done, you can use [`Enter-PSSession`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849707.aspx) to access the remote system interactively (similar to sshing into a Linux box) or [`Invoke-Command`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) to execute individual commands or scriptblocks remotely.

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy. I have got the remoting working. One important thing to do (apart from PSRemoting and Invoke-Command) was to set trust between the two environments. It was a real pain to fix that. Thank you for your time.